# Deploy Django on Azure (Windows OS)

Tags: django, azure, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I try to deploy django web app about 1 month but it wasn't working.

I can deploy it on Linux but Linux have no "MySQL in app". so I use Windows. Howerver, I can't fint "startup command" in Windows. Moreover, I have no permission to install package (i use cmd via kudu => i use python -m pip install -U --user -r requirements), so I can't run "gunircorn ...", I can't use pip install, ....

Does anyone help me deploy Django on windows web app. I extremly tired ~~ it is difficult to deploy ~~

I deploy successfully on Linux (Azure webapp)

Answer (score 0):

I think deploying a pure web app into App Service on Azure via Git on Linux is the simplest way for you. You can refer to the offical docuemnts below to know how to do it via Azure CLI or only Git.

[Deploy your first Python web app to Azure in five minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python)
[Local Git Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git)

And there is a code [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/app-service-web-python-get-started/) of Django on App Service as reference that you can know how to configure it for running on Azure.

**[More information on this SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361449/how-to-deploy-django-web-application-on-microsoft-azure-cloud-services)**

Comment: Thank you. I need using code to activate enviroment python, it's difficult to deploy on Windows (Azure)