# Visual Studio 2022 - Cant add Azure Cloud Services roles for Python

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio

I am trying to deploy a Python Django application to Azure Cloud Services with Visual Studio 2022.

My Visual Studio install includes the Python module "Azure Cloud Services core tools", along with the rest of the Python development tools.

However, no Python project template for Azure is not available to me. I only have C# and Visual Basic for Azure Cloud Service (classic and extended).

How can I build the Cloud Service in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

- Initially Iam unable to find ***Django Template*** in VS2022.
- Click on the `Install more tools and features` option

[image]

- Visual Studio Installer will be opened to Modify the Workloads
- Select the option for ***Python development*** , make sure you have selected all the ***Optional*** check boxes under ***Python Development*** and click on Modify

[image]

- Selected workloads will be Installed

[image]

- Now you can see the Django Web Templates available

[image]

- I have created a sample Django Web App ,right click on the Solution Explorer and click on Publish, Iam able to see the option to publish to Azure

[image]

- AFAIK, there is no separate template available for Azure, we need to select the ***Django Web Project*** and Publish to Azure from there.

Comment: There is no option to deploy to Cloud Services once i click Next.

Comment: Please check the [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V5TT.png) and [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Oeh.png) , Signin to the Azure Subscription

Comment: Im sorry you misunderstand. I do not want to deploy to App Service. I want to deploy to Cloud Service. your screenshots show deploying to the App Service

Comment: Could you please let me know which cloud service you are looking for ? Where exactly you want to deploy your Web App ?

Comment: I am trying to deploy to Cloud Services (Extended Support), onto cloudapp.azure.com

Comment: As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-python-ptvs), Python web and worker roles are supported up to VS 2017. Also refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361449/how-to-deploy-django-web-application-on-microsoft-azure-cloud-services) once